# Access VB6 parent form's AmbientProperties.UserMode property from interop UserControl

Tags: winforms, com-interop, vb6-migration, winforms-interop

Is there a way by which a WinForms interop UserControl hosted on a VB6 form can retrieve the parent form's `AmbientProperties.UserMode` value?

The UserControl's `DesignMode` property is false, which makes sense given that the control has been compiled and registered.

Answer (score 1):

This is such an interesting question.

According to this (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/com/ambient-properties), all ActiveX Control Containers must support the `UserMode` Ambient property.

Try using `InvokeMember` to call the `UserMode` property via IDispatch (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.invokemember?view=netframework-4.8).